# scala scoping brings in types not shown in import

Tags: scala, types

I read an article concerning that scala's type inference might have done too
much:

Given this piece of code:

```
package A1 {
  case class Foo(a: Int)

  package object A2 {
    def bar() = Foo(1)
  }
}

--
import A1.A2._
object Main extends App {
  val a: Foo = bar()  // error: not found type Foo
}
```

It won't compile as `Main` can't see `Foo` unless we also `import A1.Foo`.

Whereas if the type annotation is taken away, then it fine:

```
import A1.A2._
object Main extends App {
  val a = bar()
}
```

The author thinks this comparing to java, where we have to explicitly import whatever types we're using, would reduce readability as imports no long have complete information about the set of types we're using.

I think what he wants is that the types being used, explicitly or implicitly, need to be imported to make it clear what the code depends on and perhaps to assist some static analysis tools.

For this problem I wonder what you think about it.

EDIT:
As @flavian pointing out, this has little to do with type inference, more of how scoping works.

EDIT2:
I have a second thought on this. Maybe this question is not important if an IDE can automatically add imports(even for those used implicitly) if the developer wants to.

--

Comment: Not related to question, but related to code 
https://github.com/alexandru/scala-best-practices/issues/4

Comment: Thanks @Odomontois. The guideline is very useful. I've edited my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first example the compiler sees

```
val a: Foo = bar()
```

and doesn't know what Foo is, so it complains.

To fix this code there are three options.

```
// import Foo
import A1.Foo
val a: Foo = bar()

// use the fully qualified name
val a: A1.Foo = bar()

// let the compiler infer the type
val a = bar()
```

These all compile the same.

The last option is not avaliable to Java.

---

> The author thinks this comparing to java, where we have to explicitly import whatever types we're using

Not true.

```
// we can use Foo with no import
useFoo(x.getFoo());

// and we can use fully qualified names
A1.Foo foo = bar();
```

The compiler will add to the compiled class file a list of all classes that are needed by the class.

Comment: thank you for clarifying that. I didn't think it through the point about java.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think type inference is the question at play in here. Members propagate in scope through direct import or inheritance. If you had:

```
trait A1 {
  case class Foo(..)
}
object A2 extends A1
```

This would correctly import `Foo` into scope. Again, as far as I know this is not a type inference problem, but rather with the fact that imports and implicits propagate only through inheritance. It's more about how scoping works in Scala than anything else.

Comment: Yes you are right. As far as I know type inference matches the right company from what it can see, so this is more of a problem for scoping.